# Use JQuery to set value for dependent select upon document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Rails 4.0.3, Ruby 2.0.0

Floor is a dependent select.  It's contents, how many floors, are unknown until the building is selected.  However, this is fired in an edit(update) form.  So, the building and floor are known.  I am trying to set the current values within JQuery.  I obtain a building index and click on a building.  At that point, the edit form referenced here displays the building name.  It should also display the floor but that isn't happening. It only displays the prompt.  How to I fire the floor event when the building event fires so that both current values are selected?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    });
    $("select[name='item[building_id]']").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/floors", {building: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
            var options_html = ['<option value="">Floor?</option>'];
            $.each(data, function (index, floor) {
                if (index = 0) {options_html.push('<option value="">Floor?</option>');}
                options_html.push("<option value='" + floor.id + "'>" + floor.name + "</option>");
            });
            $('select#item_floor_id').html(options_html.join('')).prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });
    $("select[name='item[building_id]']").ready(function () {
        var building = $('#item_building_id').attr("value");
        $("#item_building_id").val(building).trigger("change");
    });
    $("select[name='item[floor_id]']").ready(function () {
        var floor = $('#item_floor_id').attr("value");
        $("#item_floor_id").val(floor);
    });
});
```

EDIT I'm not a JavaScript/JQuery expert but I don't understand why this doesn't work and has the same problem.  It attempts to select the floor before the select list is completed.  If a breakpoint is set and then resumed, it works fine...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    });
    $("select[name='item[building_id]']").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/floors", {building: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
            var options_html = ['<option value="">Floor?</option>'];
            $.each(data, function (index, floor) {
                if (index = 0) {options_html.push('<option value="">Floor?</option>');}
                options_html.push("<option value='" + floor.id + "'>" + floor.name + "</option>");
            });
            $('select#item_floor_id').html(options_html.join('')).prop('disabled', false);
        });
        var floor = $('#item_floor_id').attr("value");
        $("#item_floor_id").val(floor);
    });
    $("select[name='item[building_id]']").ready(function () {
        var building = $('#item_building_id').attr("value");
        $("#item_building_id").val(building).trigger("change");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry - can't understand your question. Can you explain what you mean by "floor event"? What is "the prompt"? What is `#item_building_id`?

Comment: @mccannf Well, we're talking buildings and floors...  I have to select a building before I know how many floors it has.  So, floors is dependent upon the building that is selected.  Thus, floors is a dependent select.  If I pick the Canton building, it has floors A through H.  If I pick the Chicago building, it has floors A through AH...

Comment: Yes, understand that. And some of the code snippet that you have shown works: http://jsfiddle.net/xuL3ndd9/3/. But still don't understand your question and what is not working.

Comment: @mccannf I want to Use JQuery to set value for dependent select upon document ready.  The form is edit and the action is update.  The object exists.  When the form is rendered, all entries should render to their current values as per the object's current state.  More simply put, when the item is selected, the building and the floor should both display the current value for the item.

Comment: @mccannf  It appears that the floor selection is just firing too early.  If I set a breakpoint on it, when I resume the code it actually works.  All I really need to do is to delay its execution until after the building change code has rendered the list of floors  Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: maybe your selector should be: $("select[name='"+item[building_id]+"']") // note the +"..."+ bit

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff  Can you provide a reference or explanation for what that does?  Thank you!

Comment: I've not read your code in detail - so I was assuming item[building_id] is a javascript array element.  If it is then it won't be seen inside the selector string - you'd need to get it evaluated and inserted into that string in the way I wrote. I could be wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a promise is your best choice still, just append it to the promise implicitly created by $.getJSON() with a .then(function(){//do stuff});  The .then() function will only fire after the success() from $.getJSON has completed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...
});
$("select[name='item[building_id]']").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("/floors", {building: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
        var options_html = ['<option value="">Floor?</option>'];
        $.each(data, function (index, floor) {
            if (index = 0) {options_html.push('<option value="">Floor?</option>');}
            options_html.push("<option value='" + floor.id + "'>" + floor.name + "</option>");
        });
        $('select#item_floor_id').html(options_html.join('')).prop('disabled', false);
    }).then(function() {
        var floor = $('#item_floor_id').attr("value");
        $("#item_floor_id").val(floor);
    });
});
$("select[name='item[building_id]']").ready(function () {
    var building = $('#item_building_id').attr("value");
    $("#item_building_id").val(building).trigger("change");
});
```

});

I have tested the above with a couple of different scenarios and in all cases the promise is executed after the select is populated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your question and your attempted solution.  The problem is quite a common one in modern web applications and there are several patterns for solving it.

If I understand this correctly, you have a chunk of HTML that contains a form in an edit context that has some fields already populated by the server code (ruby) when it is rendering the HTML, including the two select fields building_id and floor_id.

You want some javascript code that will execute on a change event for these selects.  However, I assume you also want this code to run when the page is initially loaded, acting on the values that have been preset by the server.

First of all, you are misusing .ready().  While it is available as a method on all jquery objects, it really doesn't make any sense to call it on anything but the document element (in this context anyway).  Generally you only need one .ready() call per page, and this should be used to assign your event handlers, initialize objects etc.

Second, you should not need to manually trigger select onchange event handlers.  It's there as an option, but is quite a hackie way of doing things that generally shows poor factoring of your code.  Avoid doing too much in your event handler.  Limit the callback to collecting and storing pertinent data from the event and then call another method to do the actual work.  This allows you to call the work method from other places without pretending you are firing a select event.

Your problem is not a trivial one because you want to respond to 2 separate sources of data - the inital prepopulated form as well as the users actions when changing values.  They should both be handled differently, and we shouldnt try to pretend that the server is clicking a select dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    // do stuff with the prepopulated data
    updateBuildingName();
    updateFloorName();

    // set up the event handlers for the user changing values
    $('select#building_id').on('change', buildingIDChanged);
    $('select#floor_id').on('change', floorIDChanged);
});

function updateBuildingName() {
    var building_id = $('select#building_id option:selected').val();
    var building_name = 'None';
    if (building_id) {
        building_name = $('select#building_id option:selected').text();
    }
    $('#building_name').text(building_name);
}

function updateFloorName() {
    var floor_id = $('select#floor_id option:selected').val();
    var floor_name = 'None';
    if (floor_id) {
        floor_name = $('select#floor_id option:selected').text();
    }
    $('#floor_name').text(floor_name);
}

function buildingIDChanged() {
    var building_id = $(this).val();
    fetchFloorList(building_id).then(function () {
        updateBuildingName();
        updateFloorName();
    });
}

function floorIDChanged() {
    updateFloorName();
}

function fetchFloorList(building_id) {
    $('#floor_id').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('select#floor_id').html('<option value="0">Loading data...</option>');
    return $.ajax({ ... })
    .then(function (data) {
        populateFloorList(data);
    });
}    

function populateFloorList(data) {
    var options_html = ['<option value="">Select a floor...</option>'];
    $.each(data, function (index, floor) {
        options_html.push("<option value='" + floor.id + "'>" + floor.name + "</option>");
    });
    $('select#floor_id').html(options_html);
    $('#floor_id').prop('disabled', '');
}
```

Edit : and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzxq6ofj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `.promise()` deferred object on your building to make sure that finishes first before calling your floor:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select[name='item[building_id]']").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/floors", {building: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
            var options_html = ['<option value="">Floor?</option>'];
            $.each(data, function (index, floor) {
                if (index = 0) {options_html.push('<option value="">Floor?</option>');}
                options_html.push("<option value='" + floor.id + "'>" + floor.name + "</option>");
            });
            $('select#item_floor_id').html(options_html.join('')).prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });
    $("select[name='item[building_id]']").ready(function () {
        var building = $('#item_building_id').attr("value");
        $("#item_building_id").val(building).trigger("change");
    }).promise().done(function () {
        $("select[name='item[floor_id]']").ready(function () {
            var floor = $('#item_floor_id').attr("value");
            $("#item_floor_id").val(floor);
        });
    });
});
```

This line is the key:  `.promise().done(function () {`

This will guarantee that the building is first loaded before loading the floor.

[Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)